# Getting div to center on page

Tags: css, html

I need the div to be in the center of the page at all times whether user resizes webpage or not.

I have tried using:
    margin: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right auto;

but neither of those three worked.

HTML:

```
<div id="grayinnerbackground">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#grayinnerbackground {
            margin: auto;
            width:1000px;
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for an example of what I'm talking about. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ymvDJ/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px; /* width ÷ 2 */
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ymvDJ/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you **do** want the position to be fixed, add these rules and drop the usual margin trick:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25px; // half the width of your element
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8DfnG/2/

Comment: This works perfectly, except i used -25px. I'm still looking at everyone's suggestions to find a cleaner way but for now I'm happy. Thank you very much Jeffman and the rest of you.

Comment: Note: Using fixed positioning can really make things difficult later on. Depending on what you want, you might want to reconsider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed`, change the `width` to `50px` and make sure you have a `0` before `auto` in `margin: auto`.

**Update:**

To have the div be as high as the window, be sure to set the `body` and `html` to `height: 100%;` too:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%:
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/ymvDJ/4/)

Comment: Only thing is I need it fixed, need the width and need it 100% of page height... Also, I've tried the margin: 0 auto; and nothing.

Comment: See my updated answer for info on how the have the div stretch to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This this HTML:

```
<div id="grayinnerbackground">
    foo
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#grayinnerbackground {
            margin: auto;
            width: 50px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            height: 100%;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why it didn't work until I put text into the div, checking something now.

**UPDATE**

Sigh, ok, i'm tired. If the div is empty, and you have a height of 100%, it is going to be 100% the height of its parent, the `<body>` in this case. Since there is no other content, the `<body>` has a height of 0. Give the `<div>` an absolute height, and it will pop in:

```
div#grayinnerbackground {
            margin: auto;
            width: 50px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It worked when you put the text in the div because the text gave the div the height it needed to actually show up. This is also achievable by giving the div a fixed height.

Comment: You are correct, sir. I shouldn't code after a couple beer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
position: relative
```

If that still doesn't work you may need to add this as well:

```
display: block;
```

"position: fixed" means that no matter what it stays at a x and y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
div#grayinnerbackground {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g49Mb/

More about the working here: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt